# Adding Office 365 apps to an existing Azure AD Free

Tags: azure, microsoft-office-365

I have an Azure AD Free subscription that has users. I want these users to have Office 365 (Essentially Outlook).

I want to manage this from my existing Azure if possible and I don't have an Office 365 account at this stage as I want to avoid costly merge problems if there is a standard way.
All the resources online are assuming you already have an Office 365 subscription!
What do I need to do if I already have an Azure account and no Office 365?

Answer (score 0):

Basically, you need to buy Office 365 licenses and assign them to your Azure AD users.

If you want actual services, such as Exchange Online, SharePoint Online and/or Teams, you'll also need to set them up.

Depending on your environment, synchronization between Azure AD and on-premises Active Directory may or may not be required.

Comment: I don't have anything on-premise and I am only interested in Office 365, how do I buy the licences and assign them?

Comment: You can buy office 365 licences by going to the licences tab in Azure AD and clicking add

Comment: @SamCogan There is no reference what so ever to Office in this location.

Comment: There is a link on the licences page to the "purchase services catalog", but as you can't see it, the direct link is https://admin.microsoft.com/AdminPortal/Home?ref=/catalog